# Encountered: TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default().models is undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I don't understand why it does not work. I am currently using the same exact file with the same configuration and Mongoose version but it appears that it still won't work.
Here's what my code looks like.

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: String,
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    images: [{ type: String }],
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // Make sure this line is correct
      ref: "Category",
      required: false,
    },
    properties: { type: Object },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export const Product =
  mongoose.models.Product || model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

Here's where I use it:

```
export default function NewProducts(newProducts) {
  console.log({ newProducts });
  console.log({ newProducts });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>AAa</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const newProducts = await Product.find({}, null, { sort: { _id: -1 } });

  return {
    props: {
      newProducts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newProducts)),
    },
  };
}
```

It says the error is near `mongoose.models.Product || model("Product", ProductSchema);`.

I even tried changing mongoose version like I've seen on another post but still does not change anything. I tried modifying the way I use it but still did not change.